# List items refusing to not wrap

Tags: html, css

I am creating an iframe with a header, two list items side by side, and a button.
However, I cannot get said list items to go side by side, neither can I get them to always fill the width of the screen and have equal width.

Here's my code:

```css
/** GLOBAL **/

.iframe-style {
  height: 480px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.iframe_header {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.iframe_header h1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.iframe-style .separator {
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}
/** NEWS (n) */

/ .n ul {
  padding: 0px px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.n li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.n_content {
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50%;
}
.n_content h2,
p {
  font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
}
.path {
  display: inline-block;
}
/** BUTTONS **/

.n_button {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900,100,300,400|Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="iframe.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <div class="iframe-style" style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72); border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);">
    <span class="iframe_header"><h1>Welcome back!</h1></span>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <ul class="n">
      <li>
        <span class="n_content"><h2>News</h2><p>
                                   Welcome back User!</p><p>Thanks for using Website! We are pleased to announce that we will be adding more tools in the future, contests and many tweaks to the site to improve your experience of it.</p><p>We hope you keep returning and we'll make sure you get rewarded as fast as possible for your effort!</p>
                               </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="n_content"><h2>Header 2</h2>
                               <p>Test</p>                                </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="n_button">START COMMENTING</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding css collums to your iframe: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp  also leave the `display:inline-block` how it is. I find this a very nice way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using float left.

```css
/** GLOBAL **/

.iframe-style {
  height: 480px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}


.iframe_header {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.iframe_header h1 {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.iframe-style .separator {
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

/** NEWS (n) *//

.n ul {
    padding: 0px px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.n li {
    float : left;
    width: 50%;
}

.n_content {
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 50%;
}

.n_content h2,p {
    font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
}

.path {
    display: inline-block;
}

/** BUTTONS **/

.n_button {
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900,100,300,400|Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="iframe.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
   

    <body style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                   <div class="iframe-style" style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72); border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);">
                    <span class="iframe_header"><h1>Welcome back!</h1></span>
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                       <ul class="n">
                           <li>
                               <span class="n_content"><h2>News</h2><p>
                                   Welcome back User!</p><p>Thanks for using Website! We are pleased to announce that we will be adding more tools in the future, contests and many tweaks to the site to improve your experience of it.</p><p>We hope you keep returning and we'll make sure you get rewarded as fast as possible for your effort!</p>
                               </span>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                               <span class="n_content"><h2>Header 2</h2>
                               <p>Test</p>                                </span>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                       <button class="n_button">START COMMENTING</button>
                  </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Hey that works like a charm, works well when I resize it also. Thank you!

Comment: Another thing, how can I make it so that those spans have ellipsis when page width is too small?